# NotEmpty validator doesn't work with custom form element

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I've created a custom form element for phone numbers. It is composed of a select for the international prefix and of a text for the actual phone number.

```
class Mylib_Form_Element_Phone extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml
{
    public $helper = 'formPhone';
    protected $prefix;
    protected $phone;

    public function setValue($value)
    {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_array($value) || !isset($value['prefix']) || !isset($value['phone'])) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid phone value provided');
        }
        $this->prefix = $value['prefix'];
        $this->phone = $value['phone'];
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return array(
            'prefix' => $this->prefix,
            'phone' => $this->phone
        );
    }

    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        $valid = parent::isValid($value, $context);

        if ($valid && !empty($this->phone) && empty($this->prefix)) {
            $this->addError('PHONE_PREFIX_REQUIRED');
            return false;
        }

        return $valid;
    }
}
```

My custom validation error works fine but if the element is created with `'required' => true` and i left both fields empty, no error are triggered.

How to you make the NotEmpty validator works with custom array element?